# Cannot upload image using jquerymobile

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple dialog box:

```
    <div data-role="dialog" id="uploadImage" data-title="Upload Image" data-needs-auth="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <a href="#subMenu" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    <h1>Upload Image</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->           
    <div data-role="content">                       
    <form name=uploadForm method=post enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadbi.php" data-ajax="false">
    <input type=file name=filename>
    <input type=hidden name=MAX_FILE_SIZE value=8000000>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

The problem is that it does not pass the filename field. From Firebug:

```
Post Parameters
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
MAX_FILE_SIZE   8000000
seid    6e540f68067707233241eb170ca83c43
Source
MAX_FILE_SIZE=8000000&seid=6e540f68067707233241eb170ca83c43
```

This is running under Firefox and I verified that it also fails under Chrome. It's been forever since I've dealt with file uploads in a form. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Last month I had a similar problem. Try to add  data-ajax="false" on your form definition and  see if that will help.

For more information, you could check this [link](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-correctly-submit-form-data-in-jquery-mobile/).

Comment: Hm... Maybe is somekind stupidly but try to add also name="submit" id="submit" in the submit input

Comment: Okay. Not a problem. It's been so long since I dealt with the file uploads that I forgot that the filename is NOT passed in the $_POST array (where I was looking) but the $_FILES array.

Comment: @mlewis54 did you figure out a way to do it can you please explain i have the same problem ?

Comment: Yes, look at my last comment. I was referring to the wrong variable.